Show that the function $(n+2)\zeta(n+3)-\zeta(n+2)-n-1$ is positive on $\mathbb{N}.$
I'm trying to prove the positivity of the function $(n+2)\zeta(n+3)-\zeta(n+2)-n-1$ on $\mathbb{N}$ using the inequalities
\begin{equation*}
\frac{s+1}{s}\zeta(s)\zeta(s+2)\geq \zeta^2(s+1),\quad s>1
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\zeta(s)\zeta(s+2)> \zeta^2(s+1),\quad s>1
\end{equation*}
and
$$
\zeta^2(s + 1)< \left(\frac{s + 1}{s}\right)
\left( \frac{(1 - 2^{-s})(1 - 2^{-(s+2)})}{(1 - 2^{-(s+1)})^2} \right)
\zeta(s)\zeta(s + 2), \quad s > 1.
$$

You may simply use the definition of $\zeta(s)=\sum1/n^s$, after cancellation the remaining positive terms are much larger in absolute values then negative

Is this sum  $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{n+2}{k^{n+3}}-\frac{1}{k^{n+2}}\right) $ positive for $n\in \mathbb{N}?$

Certainly: negative terms start with $k=n+3$, and they are way too small than the $k=2$ term, by the integral bound or whatever.
